# Sklearn Linear Regression giving me inaccurate accurate reading?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have an excel file with contains 3 simple columns: Unit Price, Quantity Sold, and Total. The Total is simply obtained by multiplying unit price with quantity. So i set up a simple sklearn linear regression algorithm code to predict this value:

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import *

data = pd.read_excel("Sample.xls")[["Units", "Unit Cost", "Total"]]

predict = "Total"

X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = np.array(data[predict])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)
linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linear.fit(x_train, y_train)

acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)

print(acc)
```

I ran the print function 3 times and it gave me the following results:

```
-1.517292267629657
0.9167778505657976
0.15292336331892453
```

Why am i getting this and not a 100% accuracy? The model should recognise that the prediction is simply multiplication of the frist column with the second

Comment: How big is your dataset?

Comment: around 50. enough for the model to train with

Answer (score 0):

Linear regression doesn't work that way. Plot a graph using matplotlib and see if you get straight line for training data. If your inputs are X1 and X2 your output is X1*X2 and not of the form aX1+bX2. Model is predicting correctly, What is wrong is the model application itself.